# combinatorics duplicates question

Tags: combinatorics

Julie and Louis are going on holiday and plan to bring 8 books with them. Louis has 16 books in total to choose from, and Julie has a further 24 books. Louis thinks they will each bring 4 of their own books but Julie, who is responsible for packing the books, just picks 8 books at random from the combined total of 40 books they own. What is the probability that she unintentionally picks 4 of Louis' books and 4 of her own?

How would you modify your answer if there were duplicates, eg Louis and Julie owned a copy of the same book?

I have found the answer to the first part of this question but I am unsure how to go about duplicates. I know to normally work out duplicates for combinatorics you just divide by the factorial of how many duplicates there are but I am unsure how to go about the question if the duplicates are in separate groups. eg one in Julie's books and one in Louis' books

Comment: [You already asked the question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519064/combinatorics-question-about-choices-with-different-probability) and insipidintegrator's comment has already provided you the answer.

Comment: Don't be intimidated by the comments there. All we asked was for you to make the edits so as to make look as you have provided it here.

Comment: Are you sure ? For then it doesn't matter, their books are in two compartments of $16$ and $24$ as in the simpler problem where there are no duplicates.

Comment: It would be better if you posted the **exact** question. Apart from my previous comment, there is also doubt about exactly how many duplicates there are

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please do not ask the same question twice.  Also, you should edit your question to show what you have attempted.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @InanimateBeing: So you're saying this question… is a duplicate? :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen though this is indeed a duplicate as you may see from the first link posted under the question in comments but this post itself is an improvement of it which the newbie user got confused.so posted another post. But if anything, it would be best to report the original as duplicate or ask the OP to delete the first one.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question, abcde. That's a very disrespectful way to treat those who have helped you.

Comment: DON'T VANDALIZE YOUR QUESTION!

Answer (score 0):

You are telling so many things, let me crystallize it into a clear question.

There are two books that L and J both like. Apart from these, L likes $15$ books and J likes $23$ books ($2+15+23=40$) They want to take $4$ liked books each, but unfortunately $8$ are randomly chosen. What is the probability that each gets $4$ liked books ?

Let $J_1 = \binom{23}4,\;\; J_2= \binom{23}3\binom21, \;\;J_3 = \binom{23}2\binom22$

Let $L_1 = \binom{15}4, \;\;L_2= \binom{15}3\binom21,\;\; L_3= \binom{15}2\binom22$

Then Pr $= \dfrac{J_1(L_1+L_2+L_3) + J_2(L_1+L_2) + J_3(L_1)}{\binom{40}8}$

This should give you sufficient insight for these type of problems

Comment: Glad to be of help !$\;\;$ :)

Comment: Why the downvote, if there is an error, please point out.